# Error: grub-efi-amd64-signed in Ubuntu 20.04. Trying to install packages

Tags: installation, dpkg, ubuntu-20.04, grub

I'm having problems when Iḿ trying ¿to install any package or software.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
I've already tried all the solutions mentioned in this post https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1871963, including configure the UEFI, following the next comand lines:

```
   # sudo apt-get purge grub\*
   # sudo apt-get install grub-efi
   # sudo apt-get autoremove
   # sudo update-grub
```

etc.

The error message appears even when the upgrades and is installed an app from the "Ubuntu Software" application...

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` and if that didn't fix provide the output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work :( this is the output from the terminal screen:

     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
     1 not fully installed or removed.
     After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
     Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
        installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess 
        returned error exit status 1
        Errors were encountered while processing:
        grub-efi-amd64-signed
        E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Remove the broken pkgs `grub-efi-amd64-signed`. (However I'm not very familiar with grub and if you are using grub there is a chance your system won't boot anymore.)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had this same problem the last few days. Months ago I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Win10 I had to switch the BIOS to AHCI from RAID as it wouldn't allow install. Then after install I could switch back to RAID to allow Win10 dual boot. However along some update it messed it up and I had to switch back to AHCI and reinstalled grub as above. It sorted the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the gurb installation and it worked :)